# cannot set maximum pool size when use ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I run same code on two different machined, and use Java multi threads technology like this:

```
val synchronousExecutor: ThreadPoolExecutor = {
  logger.info(s"max thread num is $threadNum")
  val executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadNum, threadNum, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue[Runnable](), threadFactory)
  executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)
  logger.info(s"max thread num is ${executor.getMaximumPoolSize}")
  executor
}
```

The behaviors on the two machines are completely different: when I set `threadnum = 30` in one machine, the active thread count in the thread pool always can not reach this number and the pool size always is 10. But another machine shows different results.

I wanna know why this happen and what should I do to increase the pool size.

Comment: How do you measure those results?

Comment: What versions of Java do you have on each machine?

Comment: Are you sure you are submitted enough concurrent jobs to take the executor past 10?  Could something else be limiting them?

Comment: @talex, the active thread count can be measured like this </br>`logger.info(s"the active count of thread in synchronousExecutor is ${synchronousExecutor.getActiveCount}")`

Comment: @BobDalgleish,i have checked each machine java version and initial config, all these things is same:`java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)`, `-XX:InitialHeapSize=395862080 -XX:MaxHeapSize=6335496192 -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC`

Comment: @Gray, I think you r right, i transform SynchronousQueue to  ArrayBlockingQueue, and then I observe the queue size and the size is always is zero.`val executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadNum, threadNum, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue[Runnable](threadNum), threadFactory)` ,      `logger.info(s"the active thread count in synchronousExecutor is ${synchronousExecutor.getActiveCount}, and task count in queue is ${synchronousExecutor.getQueue.size()}")`